# Поток сознания

Tags: пунктуация

Существует ли официально такой жанр как "поток сознания" и правда ли, его особенностью является отсутствия запятых?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ПОТОК СОЗНАНИЯ -
в литературе модернизма ХХ в. ***стиль, претендующий на непосредственное воспроизведение ментальной жизни сознания посредством сцепления ассоциаций, нелинейности, оборванности синтаксиса***. Понятие П. с. принадлежит американскому философу, одному из основателей прагматизма Уильяму Джеймсу. Он считал, что сознание подобно потоку или ручью, в котором мысли, ощущения, переживания, ассоциации постоянно перебивают друг друга и причудливо переплетаются подобно тому, как это происходит в сновидении (см. ПСИХОАНАЛИЗ). П. с. представляет собой форму, имитирующую устную речь (см. ЛИНГВИСТИКА УСТНОЙ РЕЧИ), внутренний монолог (см. ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНЫЙ ЯЗЫК). У истоков стиля П. с. были Ф. М. Достоевский ("Кроткая") и Л. Н. Толстой. Предсмертный монолог Анны Карениной, находящейся в измененном состоянии сознания под влиянием постоянного употребления морфия, представляет собой несомненный П. с.: ***"Всем нам хочется сладкого, вкусного. Нет конфет, то грязного мороженого. И Кити так же: не Вронский, то Левин. И она завидует мне. И ненавидит меня. И все мы ненавидим друг друга. Я Кити, Кити меня. Вот это правда. Тютькин, соiffeur.. Je mefais coiffer par Тютькин... (парикмахер. Я причесываюсь у Тютькина... (фр.) - прим. Л. Толстого) Я это скажу ему,когда он приедет.***" В начале ХХ в. первыми и главными представителями стиля П. с. были, несомненно, Джеймс Джойс и Марсель Пруст. Фактически весь роман "Улисс" представляет собой несколько П. с. [более полно здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_culture/881/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A)

***Что касается пунктуации, то она в ПОТОКЕ СОЗНАНИЯ вовсе не отменяется. Может быть необычной - да. Иногда запятые могут отсутствовать - тоже верно. Всё зависит от авторского решения.***

Comment: Можно уточнить, "стиль" и "жанр" - синонимы?!

Мне вот это понравилось:

Синонимы: многоречивость, многословие, недержание речи, понос слов, словесное недержание, словесный понос.

Answer (score 3):

Поток сознания - это не жанр. Кто-то определяет как стиль, мне больше нравится слово прием или принцип изображения. В остальном соглашусь с ответом Екатерины.  К слову официальный не будем придираться. Что может быть официальным в теории литературы? Упоминание в учебниках? Диссертации? По крайней мере, в "Краткой литературной энциклопедии" статья с таким названием есть. [здесь](http://feb-web.ru/feb/kle/Kle-abc/ke5/ke5-9171.htm)

Comment: > в "Краткой литературной энциклопедии" статья с таким названием есть. здесь  
  
Это можно считать официальным (во всяком случае энциклопедия именно литературная, а не непоймикакая). Но там нет отнесения этого типа литературв к **жанрам**.

Comment: Ни Екатерина, ни я не согласились со спрашивающим, что это жанр. Не понимаю сути комментария. Разве что Вы снова хотите начать спорить на пустом месте, чтобы последнее слово осталось за Вами.

Comment: ОК, хотя это по тексту и непонятно. А ведь вопрос-то именно об этом... Или я что-то не понимаю в этой жизни.

Answer (score -1):

Ну если считать что "существует" все, что было выдумано... )))
реально, конечно, для признания чего-то "жанром", надо иметь что-то повесомее слузов о том, что некто N в нем работает...